# Python error message keep appear when I enter only zero and works with other numbers

Tags: python, phone-number

I'm writing a code in Python to check the phone number.

When a user enters a number it should start with "05", its length should be 10 digits, and all characters should be numbers between 0-9.

If the user enters any wrong value there is a while statement which asks him to enter the number again.

It works fine until I put "only 0", but then a error message appears and the program stops.

What is the problem?

this is my code

```
def isValid_Mobile(Number):
    numbers=list(Number)
    if numbers[0]=="0" and numbers[1]=="5" and len(Number)==10:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

this is the input validate:

```
Number=input("Enter your phone number: ")
isValid_Mobile(Number)
check=isValid_Mobile(Number)
while check==False:
    print("INCORRECT entry, please try again")
    Number=input("Enter your phone number: ")
    check=isValid_Mobile(Number)
```

the error message: list index out of range

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging, what do you understand from this? As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're trying to access numbers[1] and when you enter only 0 or any one digit number it throws out of index error as there is no item in index 1